# How can I compare the values of two lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to compare the values of two lists.

For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

I need to check if `a` is same as `b` or not. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use

```
a == b
```

the operator `==` will compare the value of a and b, no matter whether they refer to the same object.

Answer (score 7):

```
a == b
```

This is a very simple test, it checks if all the values are equal.

If you want to check if `a` and `b` both reference the same list, you can use `is`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a is b # a and b have the same values but refer to different lists in memory
False
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b # both refer to the same list
True
```

Answer (score -2):

@jamylak's answer is what I would go with. But if you're looking for "several options", here's a bunch:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> a == b
True
```

OR

```
def check(a,b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        if a[i] != b[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

OR

```
>>> len(a)==len(b) and all((a[i]==b[i] for i in xrange(len(a))))
True
```

OR

```
def check(a,b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    for i,j in itertools.izip(a,b):
        if i != j:
            return False
    return True
```

OR

```
>>> all((i==j for i,j in itertools.izip(a,b)))
True
```

OR (if the list is made up of just numbers)

```
>>> all((i is j for i,j in itertools.izip(a,b)))
True
```

OR

```
>>> all((i is j for i,j in itertools.izip(a,b)))
True
```

Hope that satiates your appetite ;]

Comment: I presumed that `==` would already include the optimization `len(a) != len(b)`, do you know how that equality check is implemented and where I could view the source?

Comment: `i is j` works only for small numbers, and the meaning of "small" is implementation dependent. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false

Comment: Why would you reimplement `a == b`? And your examples for numbers is wrong, as @slothrop points out.

Comment: ["There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3). And "==" is *the* obvious way to do it. Don't confuse people.