# Why and how does the Python interpreter remember literal objects

Tags: python, literals, name-binding

I am surprised by the following result, using `Python 2.7.4`:

```
>>> id(5)
5068376

>>> id(5)
5068376
```

When the expression 5 is evaluated, a new object is created with the identity of 5068376. Now, I would expect that repeating the same statement would create *another* new object, whose identity would be unique, since simply evaluating an expression doesn't yield any references to the object and the object should be garbage collected.

It's not that the interpreter is reusing the same memory address either:

```
>>> id(6)
5068364

>>> id(5)
5068376
```

So what gives? Does the interpreter do behind-the-scenes binding of literals?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: You may want to summarize and post as an answer since that answers the question.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Comment: @Guvante: why would he do that? Voting to close as duplicate is the correct course of action. No need to rephrase existing answers from another question here.

Comment: @Wooble: Because while the answer is the same, I could not tell if the question was the same. I don't recognize `id` versus `is` so didn't want to claim duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a range of small numbers that are kept as singletons within Python; any reference will always return the same object and they will never be garbage collected.

```
>>> for x,y in enumerate(range(1000)):
    if x is not y:
        print x,y
        break

257 257
```

Comment: To clarify, the reason for this is because otherwise there'd be annoyingly large performance hits for things like `1+2`

Comment: Got it, thanks for the quick response. There really ought to be a mention of this in the Python data model documentation.

Comment: @Sharp3, it's an implementation detail, subject to change at any time. You really shouldn't care whether you get the same object or not.

Comment: Congrats on hitting the big 100K! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks! And congratulations on beating me to it!

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things going on here:

- Small Python integers (from -5 to 256 inclusive) are *interned*; a literal integer is translated into the exact same object for the same number. For these integers their  `id()` is going to be constant.
- The `id()` is only unique for the lifetime of the object; it can be reused later on for another object if the first object has been cleared again. You don't store your literals anywhere, so the memory address *can* be reused again:

  ```
  >>> id('foo bar')
  4572936304
  >>> id('bar baz')
  4572936304
  ```

  Here `'foo bar'` and `'bar baz'` are two distinct objects, but their lifetimes do not overlap. The first is created, passed to the `id()` function, then destroyed again. Then the second string is created, passed to `id()` and destroyed in turn.