# python: how do I do simple variable declaration?

Tags: python

My code is test I'm trying to do to figure out why `p & ~(p & (p - 1))` won't test for exponents of 2. anyway, the interpreter doesn't like `in  = 1` before the while loop for some reason.

code:

```
def getnumber(str):
    num=0
    for i in str:
        zz = ord(i)-48
        if zz<0 or zz>9:
            num=-1
            break
        else:
            num=(num*10)+zz
    return num

def testexp2(p):
    table = {1:1,2:2,4:3,8:4,16:5,32:6,64:7,128:8,256:9}
    if p & ~(p & (p - 1)):
        print "yes"
    else:
        print "no"


in = 1
while in is not -1:
    in = raw_input("> ")
    in = getnumber(in)
    if in>-1:
        testexp2(in)
    else:
        print "\nDone\n\n"
```

Comment: `in` is a reserved keyword in python. And you should use `while inp ! = -1` not `while inp is not -1`.

Comment: FYI you can do a power-of-2 test with `p & (p-1) == 0`, that's somewhat simpler.

Comment: I did that to exclude 0 from returning true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few problems:

1. `in` is reserved keyword in python, so you can't use it as a variable name.
2. `while inp is not -1` should be `while inp != -1`. ( I used `inp` instead of `in`)
3. The `getnumber` function can be reduced to:

**Code:**

```
def getnumber(strs):
    num = int(strs)
    return -1 if num < 0 else num
```

Comment: @arshajii it would only work for small integers from -5 to 256, and it's a bad idea to compare integers like that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false

Comment: The small integer caching is a Cpython implementation detail and is manifestly confusing to people having trouble with the `is not` and `!=` distinction.

Comment: @arshajii - even worse, it *will* work sometimes, but not others. It works when an an interning cache finds the same value, so that identity matching with `is` will work then. But that cache is just an optimization, not a language feature, so you are not guaranteed that it will always be checked when comparing ints. If you are testing for equality in ints, use '=='.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire That's a good point; while in CPython it will always work, it may not work in other implementations.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare a variable called `in`, that's a [reserved word](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) (or *keyword*) of the language, it's an operator that tests for membership. Simply rename it  to something else in your code:

```
txt = raw_input("> ")
txt = getnumber(txt)
```