# python objects : digging deeper

Tags: python

Hi all I know what this code does:

**1.] My first problem**

```
x = 4 
y = x
```

But what about this. Why same addresses even for this case?

```
x = 4
y = 4
id(x)
12345678
id(y)
12345678
```

**2.] My second problem**

```
x = 42 
y = x 
x = x + 1 
print x  # Prints 43
print y  # Prints 42


x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
x[0] = 4
print x # Prints [4, 2, 3]
print y # Prints [4, 2, 3]
```

But why is it that in the case of list, both `x` & `y` got mutated together by the command `x[0] = 4`.
What is so different with lists, in such a behavior?
What makes them behave like this?
And most importantly what is the benefit of such a behavior?
why cant list, variables, tuples have all the properties of each other?

Answer (score 8):

1. Small integers are [cached in CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false), that's why their id's are same.
2. Integers are immutable, so modifying(i.e assigning it to a new object) one will not affect the other references.
3. Lists are mutable, so modifying any reference(in-place modification) to a mutable object will affect other references as well.
4. Small strings can have [same id's too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756699/is-operator-behaves-differently-when-comparing-strings-with-spaces):

Integer example:

```
>>> x = 100
>>> y = x
>>> id(x),id(y)
(165193204, 165193204)
>>> x += 1
>>> id(x), id(y)    #`x` now points to a new object, `y` still points to the old object
(165193192, 165193204)
```

Comment: "modifying one will not affect the other references" - you're not modifying it. You're replacing it with a new one.

Comment: What about this case -- >  
 id(4);
 28490784,    f=4;id(f); 28490784 . So even if I just type "4", its given an address? and typing f=4,f refers to that "4"??

Comment: @vinita Yes, everything in python has some address even if they are not assigned to any variable.

Comment: @user2357112 Fixed the wordings, I guess it's better now.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem can be answered with memory optimization. If you dig a little further, for example:

```
x = 4
y = 4
# Both (may) have the same id
x += 1
# id of x and y will now be different
```

The second is *reference semantics*. Since just about everything in Python is really a reference, setting `x = y` is simply saying *point `y` to the same thing that `x` points at*. If you actually want a completely separate copy, you'll need to say so:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = x[:]
x[0] = 5
y
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```