# Optimization with integer and strings

Tags: python

I read somewhere around that python, for optimization target, makes some caches of small integers and strings, so I made some experimentations.

From `test1.py`:

```
x = 150
n = int(input('number: '))
print(id(x))
print(id(n))
```

So I launched it:

```
*****@***** ~/Desktop $ python3 test1.py 
number: 150
10459808
10459808
```

From `test2.py`:

```
x = 'hi'
s = (input('write: ')).strip()
print(id(x))
print(id(s))
```

then:

```
*****@***** ~/Desktop $ python3 test2.py 
write: hi
140124156034832
140124155359336
```

Why are integers optimized at run-time and strings not?

Infact if I have:

```
x = 'hi'
s = 'hi'
print(id(x))
print(id(s))
```

it returns same ids. So why are strings optimized only at compile-time?

Comment: Completely different caching strategies. All small integers are cached, but only certain string literals used in code and identifiers are interned. The answer on the dupe explains the rules for when a string is interned.

Comment: For integers: [Python "is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/306313)

Comment: Also related: [Why (0-6) is -6 = False?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false)

Comment: As to why: The set of small integers between -5 and 256 is a *finite set*. We know exactly how many elements need to be cached, so that's easy and manageable. For strings, there is no such small set.

Comment: Strings are cached to speed up name lookups, mostly. An interned string can use pointer comparisons, faster than character by character value comparisons. As Python uses dictionaries almost exclusively for name lookups, that's a good thing to have. For user input, not so much.