# Prime number printer stops at 251, why?

Tags: python

I started learning Python today, and I came up with the idea of creating a program that prints all the prime numbers from 0 to 10 000. I managed to make my program print out all primes until 251, at which point it stops printing out numbers. Why does it do this?

Here is the code:

```
for numberToCheck in range(2,10000):
    divider = 2
    while numberToCheck > divider:
        if numberToCheck % divider is 0:
            break
        else:
            divider += 1
    if numberToCheck is divider:
        print(numberToCheck, "is a prime number.")
```

Comment: That ` (backtick) causes a syntax error. You may want to edit it and remove the ` at the end of the code section unless it is markup for formatting.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In addition to your question, you could make this function about twice as efficient by not checking the modulo of the numbers greater than half of `numberToCheck`. For any given `numberToCheck`, a number greater than that number divided by two can't possibly be one of its divisors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers), [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: @Alex can't you limit it to the square root of the number to check?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I think so, yes! Even more efficient :)

Answer (score 74):

The problem is that you are using `is` instead of `==`. The `is` operator performs *object identity* comparison, which "happens to work" for all numbers below `256` due to **implementation details**. `251` is the biggest prime below 256 (check [here](http://www.miniwebtool.com/list-of-prime-numbers/?to=300), next prime is 257) and after that the `is` returns `False`:

```
>>> 254 + 1 is 255
True
>>> 255 + 1 is 256
True
>>> 256 + 1 is 257
False
```

The equality operator is `==`:

```
>>> 254 + 1 == 255
True
>>> 255 + 1 == 256
True
>>> 256 + 1 == 257
True
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `==` to check equality of numbers:

```
for numberToCheck in range(2,10000):
    divider = 2
    while numberToCheck > divider:
        if numberToCheck % divider is 0:
            break
        else:
            divider += 1
    if numberToCheck == divider:
        print(numberToCheck, "is a prime number.")
```

[`Is`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.is_) operator is used to check the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) of two objects while `==` operator check their values.

Python implements an Array of integers for values between `-5` to `256`, and when you create an int object in this range, you get a reference to the existing array implementation. That's why `id` of all integers objects in this range is same but it is different for integers objects outside this range, as seen below:

```
>>> a = -6
>>> b = -6
>>> a is b      # a and b has different id
False

>>> a = -5
>>> b = -5
>>> a is b      # a and b has same id
True

>>> a = 256
>>> b = 256
>>> a is b      # a and b has same id
True

>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> a is b      # a and b has different id
False
```

And this is the reason, your program prints primes till `251` but not the [next](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt) prime `257` and afterwards, however your program does run till `numberToCheck` reaches `9999`.

Also, you might consider a faster algorithm to generate primes, such as [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Basically, you should check divisibility of `numberToCheck` with *all primes* between `2` and ( previously found prime or square root of  `numberToCheck`, whichever is less ).

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the last `if`. Change it from

```
if numberToCheck is divider:
```

to

```
if numberToCheck == divider:
```

Explanation:
`is` tests if refences are equals while `==` check the equality of values (more specifically it calls `__eq__` method on your elements)

The reasons why you have the first primes to print up to 251 is because python cache all small integers.

For example:

```
>>> 100 == 10**2
True
>>> 100 is 10**2
True
>>> 1000 == 10**3
True
>>> 1000 is 10**3
False
```

(Example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/1450754))
You should use `is` only to check references (objects that should not only be equals but the same instance) or to compare to `None`.

Answer (score 3):

Never compare integers with `is`. Always use `==`.

`==` should be used to compare numbers.

Here is the fixed code:

```
for numberToCheck in range(2,10000):
divider = 2
while numberToCheck > divider:
    if numberToCheck % divider == 0:
        break
    else:
        divider += 1
if numberToCheck == divider:
    print(numberToCheck, "is a prime number.")
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you used `is`. `is` doesn't check for equality, it checks for an object's identity (memory address); is object **a** the same as object **b**?

**Refer to these questions:**

[Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

[Why (0-6) is -6 = False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476190/why-0-6-is-6-false?lq=1)

---

To solve your problem:

```
def prime(numberToCheck):
    divider = 2
    while numberToCheck > divider:
        if numberToCheck % divider == 0:
            break
        else:
            divider += 1

        if numberToCheck == divider:
            print(numberToCheck, "is a prime number.")
```

A little trivial note here, but might be crucial in larger applications: I created a function called `prime` to *maximize code re-use*. Now you can pass the `prime` function whatever number you like to check if it's prime or not, way better than hard coding the number that you want to test!

Answer (score 2):

You must not compare numbers with `is`. Use always `==` for equality testing.

Answer (score 2):

you are using is instead of ==.
Anyhow, code wise youre wasting resources checking for primes like this. you should only check from 2 to sqrt(n) and you should preferably keep the prime numbers and check only them until you reach them, for instance youre checking if the number 41 is a prime, check prime numbers 2 3 5 and then you know it isnt a prime (because all the other numbers between the prime and the sqrt are not prime so you already checked them)
create a list of primes as you go.

try this code:

```
import math
primes = [2]
for n in range(3,100):
    for i in primes:
        if n in primes:
            break
        if n%i == 0:
            break
        if i> math.sqrt(n):
            primes.append(n)
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) will help you why not to use is

```
In [5]: a = 254+1

In [6]: b = 255

In [7]: a is b  # both are same objects
Out[7]: True

In [8]: id(a)
Out[8]: 37644344 # id of a

In [9]: id(b)
Out[9]: 37644344   # same id as a
```

for > 256

```
In [10]: a = 256+1

In [11]: b = 257

In [12]: a is b # both are different objects but values are same
Out[12]: False

In [13]: id(a)
Out[13]: 39721992 # id of a

In [14]: id(b)
Out[14]: 39722592 # new id created not same as a
```

`is` always compares with objects not values

why only upto 256?

from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong)

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all
>   integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you
>   actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

when you assign `a=255` just you are adding `a` as referring excisting 255. when `a=257` new int type object will be created